# How to fix Argument of type '"email"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]' error?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

The Angular 5 application works fine but I am getting the following error while building it with production. It also builds fine with `ng build` but not with `ng build --prod`.

> Argument of type '"email"' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'string[]'.

The code on the line:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" required>
  <mat-error *ngIf="form.hasError('email', 'email') && !form.hasError('required', 'email')">
    Please enter a valid email address
  </mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="form.hasError('required', 'email')">
    Email is <strong>required</strong>
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

And form:

```
private createForm() {
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    password: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you need to wrap your second `'email'` parameter in an array based on Angular's source code ([line 520-526](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2686219fcee938fbb4359aa6318ffd97f91b0240/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L520-L526)):

```js
/**
 * Returns true if the control with the given path has the error specified. Otherwise
 * returns false.
 *
 * If no path is given, it checks for the error on the present control.
 */
hasError(errorCode: string, path?: string[]): boolean  { return !!this.getError(errorCode, path); }
```

I believe the reason that it actually works in your regular build is because although it technically is invalid, the code that eventually gets executed has a call signature that accepts `Array<string|number> | string` ([line 37-56](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2686219fcee938fbb4359aa6318ffd97f91b0240/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L37-L56)).

```js
function _find(control: AbstractControl, path: Array<string|number>| string, delimiter: string) {
    ...
}
```

*Note: your templates are not ran through the typing system in non-AOT mode and hence this doesn't pop up until you do a `--prod` build.*

Comment: Great explanation. Fixed the problem

Comment: For future reference, it seems like someone is working on a pull request that will resolve this so that you can send just a string to keep it consistent. Not sure when it will land. https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/20211

Comment: In short, replace `hasError('email', 'email')` with `hasError('email', ['email'])`